# Evaluating $ \lim_{x\to \infty} x \left({{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}^{x}-\frac{1}{e}}\right)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate the following: 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to \infty}
>  x \left({{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}^{x}-\frac{1}{e}}\right)$$

I tried to first solve the interior portion as $1^\infty$ indeterminate form but ended up getting a different indeterminate form of $\infty\cdot 0$.

Comment: Have you tried substitution, $ x+1=y$?

Comment: Not yet but I did try $ y=1/X $

Comment: @PeterForeman I am unaware of the concept. I am just a school going student.

Comment: WELCOME! "school going student".

Comment: @Piquito I am actually one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$y={\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}^{x}\implies \log(y)=x \log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)=-x \log\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)$$

Now, using Taylor expansion
$$\log\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$\log(y)=-1+\frac{1}{2 x}-\frac{1}{3 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2 e x}-\frac{5}{24 e
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$x\left(y- \frac 1e\right)=\frac{1}{2 e}-\frac{5}{24 e x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Use the above formula for $x=10$ (quite small). You should get $\frac{23}{48 e}\approx 0.176276$ while, using your pocket calculator, the result would be $\approx 0.176638$.

Comment: Nicely implemented

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x
&=\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{-x}\\
&=\left(1+t\right)^{-1/t}\quad\left(t=\frac1x\right)\\
&=\exp{\left(-\frac{\ln{\left(1+t\right)}}{t}\right)}\\
&=\exp{\left(-\frac{t-t^2/2+o(t^2)}{t}\right)}\quad(\text{as }t\to0)\\
&=\exp{\left(-\left(1-\frac{t}2+o(t)\right)\right)}\\
&=\exp{\left(-1+\frac{t}2+o(t)\right)}\\
&=\frac1e\exp{\left(\frac{t}2+o(t)\right)}\\
&=\frac1e\left(1+\frac{t}2+o(t)\right)\quad(\text{as }t\to0)\\
&=\frac1e+\frac{t}{2e}+o(t)\\
\end{align}$$
Hence our limit becomes
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x-\frac1e\right)
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac1t\left(\frac1e+\frac{t}{2e}+o(t)-\frac1e\right)\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac1t\left(\frac{t}{2e}+o(t)\right)\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{1}{2e}+o(1)\right)\\
&=\frac1{2e}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you I understood some of it